# my local storage data does not appear! -Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this showModalBottomSheet where I can input text in `TextFormField` widget defined as such:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
                useRootNavigator: true,
                context: context,
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                    top: Radius.circular(24),
                  ),
                ),
                builder: (context) {
                  return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setModalState) {
                    return Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
                      child: Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            TextFormField(
                              validator: (String? value) {
                                if (value!.isEmpty)
                                  return 'Please enter name';
                              },
                              controller: detailsController,
                              style: TextStyle(),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                              ),
                            TextFormField(
                              controller: nameController,
                              style: TextStyle(),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                    _save();
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                            content:
                                                Text('Done'))); }});  },
                              child: Text('save'),
```

---

**when I click the save button, it should go back to the home with the data from TextField, but It does not appear!**

This is where they should appear:

```
ListView(children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: storage.ready,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
            if (!initial) {
              var items = storage.getItem('reminder');
              if (items != null) {
                list.items = List<Data>.from((items as List).map((item) =>
                    Data(
                        id: item['id'],
                        name: item['name'],
                        details: item['details'],
                        save: item['save'])));
              }
              initial = true;
            }
            List<Widget> widgets = list.items.map((item) {
              return remindersCard(item.name, item.details);
            }).toList();
            return Column(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: ListView(
                  children: widgets,
                  itemExtent: 50.0,
```

My local storage functions is:

```dart
_addReminder(String name, String details) {
    setState(() {
      final item = new Data(id: id, name: name, details: details, save: true);
      list.items.add(item);
      id++;
      _saveToStorage();
      print('must');
    });
  }
```

Comment: ` _addReminder(String name, String details) {
    setState(() {
      final item = new Data(id: id, name: name, details: details, save: true);
      list.items.add(item);
      id++;
      _saveToStorage();
      print('must');
    })`

Answer (score 0):

I made you a [minimal exemple](http://minimal%20exemple) of what you're tried to archieve.
We can't really help you since the code that you send is incomplete, and we can't have the content of the `saveToStorage` function for exemple.

I hope that my [minimal exemple](https://dartpad.dev/740162cc35763bb9d1ed991ca103eb9e?null_safety=true) can help you debug yourself.

Comment: thank you, but The code is actually long, that is why I could not put all necessary things.
well the problem is complicated now, new error has thrown :( I tried to upload the code into git hub, if you have a time can you please check it? [link](https://github.com/RarLasebai/reminder)

Comment: I made you a pull request on your repository, I made some improvement of readability and maintainability of your project as well as fixing the creation of your reminders. @AbrarLasebai